What changed in TeXForm in V 14.1?
In Version 14.1 on windows 10 I get this error calling TeXForm on solution obtained from DSolve. No error in V 14.  This is known error. see how-to-catch-this-error-from-texform-texformunspt
A workaround is to use InputForm but this produces bad Latex.
The question is: What changed in V 14.1 to cause this new TeXForm error for this specific example which used to work OK in V 14.0?
ode = D[y[x], {x, 3}] + 3*D[y[x], {x, 2}] - 9*D[y[x], x] - 5*y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
TeXForm[sol]

Gives
TeXForm::unspt

error:
TeXForm of DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`HolonomicAttached$$},FrameBox[ButtonBox[GridBox[{{FEPrivate`Switch[Root,etc...

Below is screen shot comparing the output from V 14.
Version 14.1



Workaround is
ode = D[y[x], {x, 3}] + 3*D[y[x], {x, 2}] - 9*D[y[x], x] - 5*y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
TeXForm[InputForm@sol]

But the Latex now is now bad.

Version 14.0

May be someone knows some setting in Frontend changed in V 14.1 to cause this? Has there been changes made by WRI in TeXForm in V 14.1 from V 14.0 ? Could the new Semantic Highlighting in V 14.1 have anything to do with this?
Update
I think now it is related to the RooT formating? I found second example giving same error and it also has same Root type expression in the solution being given to TeXForm
ode = D[y[t], {t, 4}] + 4*D[y[t], {t, 3}] + 3*y[t] == t
sol = DSolve[ode, y[t], t]


TeXForm[sol]


InputForm[sol]

gives
{{y[x] -> E^(x*Root[-5 - 9*#1 + 3*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 1, 0])*C[1] + E^(x*Root[-5 - 9*#1 + 3*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 2, 0])*
     C[2] + E^(x*Root[-5 - 9*#1 + 3*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 3, 0])*C[3]}}

And TeXForm does not like something about the above. Same for first example above.

Indeed, it seems it is connected to the new Root formatting (and the more elaborate dialog that appears when you click on it). It seems that they have not yet enabled this formatting in Wolfram Cloud, and TeXForm works normally there ...

Well, it's a bug. They've changed MakeBoxes of Root objects to implement the new formatting, but they didn't make the changes for the TeXForm. As a simple workaround, you can use:
BoxForm`$UseUnifiedRootTemplateBox = False;



Another error in TeXForm: FoxH[{{{1/2, 1}}, {{1/3, 2}}}, {{{1/4, 3}}, {{\[Pi], 4}}},    x] // TeXForm ?

@MariuszIwaniuk, hm, but did this ever even work? I get the same error in v13.3 ...
